# How to make /dev/loop0 gathered as ansible_devices

Tags: ansible, block-device, network-block-device

Let me try to be clearer :

```
ansible localhost  -m setup
```

Is not showing any block devices :

```
"ansible_devices": {},
```

This host is using /dev/nbd0 as its root device.

Now I was wondering, for my particular needs, how I could fill this gathered facts with my block device, for instance I'd like to fake a /dev/sda which would be a loop device.
The issue is not about how to create this block device, but how to get it gathered by Ansible?

Thank you for any suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can't do this without coding.
Out of the box Ansible drops any block devices with `virtual` in it path. (see [code](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/module_utils/facts.py#L1401))

You can patch this code to include that devices or write your custom module to gather information about block devices.

Comment: Thanks, this is a precise answer :)